# What would happen if I deleted all the files associated with vBulletin?

Tags: vbulletin

I would like to completely take down the vBulletin forum running out of a subfolder of a site.  I have already removed access to the bulletin via .htaccess, but now I would like to get rid of the whole shebang.

Can I just go in via ftp and remove all of the vBulletin files or will that cause problems?

The reason I want to get rid of the bulletin now, other than for security and resource conservation, is because now, after a move to a new server, I am receiving emails of database errors (I am assuming this is because the bulletin didn't get hooked up to the database at the new server).

If it makes any difference, this is the error:

mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Unknown MySQL server host 'blah.blah.blah.some.url.associated.with.my.old.hosts.nameserver.com' (1)
/path/to/my/forum/includes/class_core.php on line 317

Thanks in advance for any advice/info you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to completely remove vbulletin you want to remove all the files in FTP and delete the database as well. the database is usually a lot larger then the forum files. but to just stop the errors your getting removing the ftp files will work.

Comment: Thanks.  That is exactly what I did and there were no problems.